# Will latest version of geofire for java (2.1.1) work with latest Firebase android sdk?

Tags: java, android, firebase, geolocation, geofire

I want to use geofire in my android app to retrieve locations from Firebase realtime database. But not sure if the latest version of Firebase android is compatible with geofire 2.1.1 which is the last released version for java. Please let me know if i can proceed with geofire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GeoFire 2.x** is based on the new **3.x release of Firebase** and it will works with latest [Firebase Android SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) version (11.0.2).

Comment: Thank you for your response!